# Handling and parsing json data to React components

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios

I am fairly new to React and trying to build a dashboard that displays data from three different sensors. The data about the sensors is stored in one json (each sensor has an ID and name), this json is served to the client using express and then using axios to get the data into my Main react component. This data is then parsed down to SensorList where it is used to create each Sensor component, setting the key to each one with the sensor ID provided.

In a separate json I have all the data returned from each sensor (sensorId, time and value). So far I have got to a point where I am using axios in the sensor component to get the json data, currently it is pulling in all the data for every sensor to each of the three created components and then passing the timestamp data to a LastReported component and the value data to a LatestValue component.

With the current setup I am looking for a way to only get the data for the specific sensor I need from the json using axios but am unsure how to do this? As I mentioned I have set the Sensor component key to that of the sensor ID given in the first json, but how do I then tell the Sensor component to get the corresponding data from the second json rather than all the data for each sensor?

Failing that I was thinking once I have all the data in the Sensor component I could just parse down the relevant data based on the sensor key, but again I am unsure on how to do this?

Also I know having axios doing the get request in the components isn't the best idea, but this is an exercise in getting to grips with React on its own and as such I am not using Redux or Flux.

First json...

```
[
  {
    "id": "46c634d04cc2fb4a4ee0f1596c5330328130ff80",
    "name": "external"
  },
{
    "id": "d823cb4204c9715f5c811feaabeea45ce06736a0",
    "name": "office"
  },
{
    "id": "437b3687100bcb77959a5fb6d0351b41972b1173",
    "name": "common room"
  }
]
```

Sample of data json...

```
[
  {
    "sensorId": "437b3687100bcb77959a5fb6d0351b41972b1173",
    "time": 1472120033,
    "value": 25.3
  },
{
   "sensorId": "437b3687100bcb77959a5fb6d0351b41972b1173",
   "time": 1472119853,
   "value": 25.1
 },
{
  "sensorId": "437b3687100bcb77959a5fb6d0351b41972b1173",
  "time": 1472119673,
  "value": 25.1
},
```

Components....

```
var Main = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      sensors: []
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var _this = this;
    this.serverRequest =
      axios
        .get("http://localhost:3000/sensors.json")
        .then(function(result) {
          _this.setState({
            sensors: result.data
          });
        })
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  },

  render: function() {
    var {sensors} = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <SensorList sensors={sensors}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var SensorList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var {sensors} = this.props;
    var renderSensors = () => {
      return sensors.map((sensor) => {
        return (
          <Sensor key={sensor.id} {...sensor}/>
        );
      });
    };

    return (
      <div>
        {renderSensors()}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Sensor = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      data: []
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var _this = this;
    this.serverRequest =
      axios
        .get("http://localhost:3000/data.json")
        .then(function(result) {
          _this.setState({
            data: result.data
          });
        })
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  },

  render: function() {
    var {name} = this.props;
    var {data} = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {name}
        <LatestValue data={data}/>
        <LastReported data={data}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What's not working? Any errors? Your question is quite confusing.

Comment: No errors. My question is how do I access the data in the json file that is specific to the corresponding sensor component. Each sensor component has a key based on the id in the first json file, this is set in the SensorList component. The Sensor component makes a get request but currently just pulls in all the data, I need it to pull in the data based on the sensorId key.

Answer (score 0):

Well, right now you're making the same api call twice in both `Main.js` and `Sensor.js`. One of the most common state management practices in React is to contain state in a parent component and then pass that state down to child components. This keeps state in one place and makes debugging down the line easier.

I would rewrite components to look like this:

**Edited**

```
var Main = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      sensors: [],
      sensorsData: []
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var _this = this;
    this.serverRequest =
      axios
        .get("http://localhost:3000/sensors.json")
        .then(function(result) {
          _this.setState({
            sensors: result.data
          });
        }) // chain api calls to obtain ALL data needed
        .get("http://localhost:3000/data.json")
        .then(function(result) {
          _this.setState({
            sensorsData: result.data
          });
        })
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  },

  render: function() {
    var {sensors, sensorsData} = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <SensorList sensors={sensors} dataList={sensorsData}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var SensorList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var {dataList, sensors} = this.props;
    var renderSensors = () => {
      return sensors.map((sensor) => {
        dataList.map((data) => {
           if (data.sensorId === sensor.id) {
            return (
             <Sensor key={data.sensorId} name={sensor.name} value={data.value} time={data.time}/>
           );
          }
        })    
      });
    };

    return (
      <div>
        {renderSensors()}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Sensor = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var {name, time, value} = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        {name}
        <LatestValue value={value}/>
        <LastReported time={time}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

There's a great tutorial on React's props and state [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_props_overview.htm)

Comment: thanks! But I am calling two different apis which is causing me the confusion. I have two json: 'sensors.json' containing 'id' and 'name' keys for 3 sensors, I am setting the key for 'Sensor.js' to this 'id' key. The 2nd json 'data.json' contains all the data from the sensors, with the keys 'sensorId', 'value' and 'time'. The 'sensorId' in 'data.json' corresponds to 'id' in 'sensors.js'. I need to somehow make 2 different api calls in 'Main.js' and set the component id and 'name' prop from 'sensors.json', and then set the 'value' and 'time' props of each sensor from 'data.json'?

Comment: @LukeAveil Sorry I missed the part with the two different JSON files. I updated my response. The main idea here is that the two mapping functions will access to both the current sensor.json and data.json info and can pass along that info via props.

Comment: Thanks, I have pretty much everything working now! One last question..currently the renderSensor function is only passing the 1st element from the value and time arrays to the corresponding Sensor. This is fine for the the current child components, but I need to make a Graph component that takes in the whole arrays of value and time of its parent Sensor component. How would I create arrays for all the time data and value data for each sensor? I understand how the current single values are being passed, just unsure now how also add the full arrays as props...